changing fontawesome icon loses the `title` element
I am trying to change a fontawesome icon (which is automatically switched out from an <i> element with a title attribute, to an <svg> element with a nested <title> element), by changing the class on the resulting <svg> element. However I also need to update the nested <title> element, but I am seeing that changing the class will result in the nested <title> element being removed. How should I update the <title> element? I might also add that I'm not using any modules, I'm simply using the fontawesome script from a cdn:
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/js/all.min.js"></script>



const getIconOuterHTML = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const iconEl = document.querySelector('#commentIcon');
      let output = $('<div>').text(iconEl.outerHTML).html();
      //console.log(output);
      output = output.replaceAll('&gt;&lt;', '&gt;\n&lt;');
      resolve(output);
    }, 200);
  });
}

$(document).ready(async () => {
  document.querySelector('#htmlRepresentation').innerHTML = await getIconOuterHTML();
});

$(document).on('click', '#switchIconBtn', async (ev) => {
  const iconEl = document.querySelector('#commentIcon');
  const titleElId = iconEl.getAttribute('aria-labelledby');
  const titleEl = iconEl.querySelector(`#${titleElId}`);
  if( iconEl.classList.contains('fa-comment-dots') ) {
    iconEl.classList.remove('fa-comment-dots');
    iconEl.classList.add('fa-comment-medical');
    if(titleEl !== null){
      titleEl.textContent = 'add a comment';
    } else {
      alert('could not find title element');
    }
  } else {
    iconEl.classList.remove('fa-comment-medical');
    iconEl.classList.add('fa-comment-dots');
    if(titleEl !== null){
      titleEl.textContent = 'edit comment';
    } else {
      alert('could not find title element');
    }
  }
  document.querySelector('#htmlRepresentation').innerHTML = await getIconOuterHTML();
});
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/js/all.min.js"></script>
<i class="fas fa-comment-medical" title="add a comment" id="commentIcon"></i>

<div><button id="switchIconBtn" style="margin-top: 15px;">Switch icon and title</button></div>
<div>Resulting HTML:</div>
<pre id="htmlRepresentation"></pre>



As you can see in the resulting HTML representation, clicking on the button which changes the icon class will result in the <title> element getting removed. How should I approach updating the title?

Wrap the i in a span and set the title on the span. FontAwesome will rewrite the SVG completely and it seems it is losing whatever title the i had

Are you using the really complicated setTimout promise to mock some ajax lag?

@mplungjan because fontawesome takes some time to update the DOM, so it is waiting until fontawesome has finished updating the DOM. It would be better to use a callback, if I had access to fontawesome's methods (I believe that would be possible when importing packages rather than using the default script).

@mplugjan for now I'm following your suggestion of wrapping in a span and updating the title on the span. Unless there is access to a fontawesome callback (without using module imports), I think this might be the only way to handle this situation.

Now check


const getIconOuterHTML = () => {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    const iconEl = document.querySelector('#commentIcon');
                    let output = $('<div>').text(iconEl.outerHTML).html();
                    //console.log(output);
                    output = output.replaceAll('&gt;&lt;', '&gt;\n&lt;');
                    resolve(output);
                }, 200);
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(async () => {
            document.querySelector('#htmlRepresentation').innerHTML = await getIconOuterHTML();
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#switchIconBtn', async (ev) => {
            const iconEl = document.querySelector('#commentIcon');
            const titleElId = iconEl.getAttribute('aria-labelledby');
            const titleEl = iconEl.querySelector(`#${titleElId}`);
            if( iconEl.classList.contains('fa-comment-dots') ) {
                iconEl.classList.remove('fa-comment-dots');
                iconEl.classList.add('fa-comment-medical');
                if(titleEl !== null){
                    titleEl.textContent = 'add a comment';
                } else {
                    alert('could not find title element');
                }
            } else {
                iconEl.classList.remove('fa-comment-medical');
                iconEl.classList.add('fa-comment-dots');
                if(titleEl !== null){
                    titleEl.textContent = 'edit comment';
                } else {
                    alert('could not find title element');
                }
            }

            // Manually update title
            const newTitle = document.createElement('title');
            newTitle.textContent = titleEl.textContent;
            iconEl.querySelector('svg').appendChild(newTitle);
            document.querySelector('#htmlRepresentation').innerHTML = await getIconOuterHTML();
        });
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/js/all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <i class="fas fa-comment-medical" title="add a comment" id="commentIcon"></i>
    <div>
        <button id="switchIconBtn" style="margin-top: 15px;">Switch icon and title</button>
    </div>
    <div>Resulting HTML:</div>
    <pre id="htmlRepresentation"></pre>




this still doesn't work, because fontawesome changes the DOM after you have appended the child. So the appended <title> element is still removed. We would need access to a fontawesome callback to wait until fontawesome has finished updating the DOM.

This answer doesn't explain what you've changed to solve the problem. You should add some explanatory text to the answer - not just "Now check".
